# Is it recommended to use any() or a specific value for unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, any

I am curious about the best / recommended approach to follow when writing a unit test.

If I can easily create the specific values that would get passed for a function, should I create those in my unit tests and use them? Or can I use `any()` to mock for all values?

```
class Foo {
    bool func1(String abc, int xyz, Bar bar) {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

If I have a class like this that I want to mock for a specific behavior, which is a better approach?

```
@Mock
Foo mockFoo;
```

1. ```
   Bar dummyBar = getTestBar();
   when(mockFoo.func1("value1", 1, dummyBar)).thenReturn(true);
   ```
2. ```
   when(mockFoo.func1(anyString(), anyInt(), any())).thenReturn(true);
   ```

I am trying to identify when to use each. I feel using specific values will be better whenever possible and if it is simple to create those values. Use `any()` only when it is not easy to create such objects. i.e. Say I am refactoring a codebase and I see almost all unit tests are using `any()` even if I could use specific values. Will it be worth doing some cleanup on the code and make the unit tests use specific values?

Comment: that depends on what you want to be tested. do you want to test for specific values? do you just want to test no matter what call?

Comment: If I have an option to use a specific value, in those cases which would be a better option?

Comment: if you are testing for a specific scenario, use the specific values. That way, if your code does something unexpected and uses other params than the ones you expect, you'll know

Comment: Of course 1. is "better",  more exact (especially in a complex test context/with many tests) 2. can be sufficient (quicker, simpler...without "dirtying" the context!??) In any case: you cannot mix both approaches (in one `when`)..so sometimes you just *have to* use "any"...

Comment: @xerx593 sure you can mix, no? `when(mockFoo.func1(eq("value1"), eq("1"), any(Bar.class)).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: ..runtime exception,@knittl (with detailed description...https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485861/592355) (the last time I tried this, maybe newer Mockito can do it... [nope, still so](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1398)!)

Comment: @xerx593 Using the `eq` matcher is not the same as using raw values. Maybe we were both saying different things :) Nevertheless, it is still possible to match some specfic values while ignoring other parameters' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function `install(String id)`, any of the following are possible:

- `id` will be a random and unpredictable set of characters such that `anyString()` is the best you can do. If you were to pick a value, it risks the test failing at random, making the code *brittle* or *flaky*.
- `id` should be `"yourProgramName"` specifically, and any deviation should fail the test. This is where `eq` and raw  values would be appropriate.
- `id` should be `"yourProgramName"`, but that's important to some test other than the one you're writing right now, so it should be `eq` in the `id`-validating test and `anyString` here.

It is entirely up to you: You'll need to pick which parameters matter to your test, and whether your test errs on the side of *brittle* (failing when it should pass) or permissive (passing when it should fail).

---

As a side note, you can mix any combination of specific matchers like `eq` and general matchers like `anyString`, or you can use all real values that test `equals` just like `eq`; [you just can't mix both styles in the same call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729215/1426891).

```java
/* Any mix of matchers is OK, but you can't mix unwrapped values. Use eq() instead. */
/*  bad: */ when(mockFoo.func1(   "example" , anyInt(), any())).thenReturn(true);
/* good: */ when(mockFoo.func1(eq("example"), anyInt(), any())).thenReturn(true);

/* Unwrapped values are OK as long as you use them for every parameter you pass. */
/* good: */ when(mockFoo.func1(   "example" ,    0 ,    bar1 )).thenReturn(true);
/* same: */ when(mockFoo.func1(eq("example"), eq(0), eq(bar1))).thenReturn(true);
```